# Javascript unwanted lines connecting moving arcs

Tags: javascript

So i have this basic script which makes 4 circles move around a centre, and I have put in two circles which are the route which the circles follow.. The problem is that there's odd unwanted lines joining the circles to the stationary one's. I think it may be because the line for the circles `ctx.arc(cx, cy, 200, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);` is within the draw function. Does anyone know how to solve this? (Placing the stationary circles outside the draw function causes them to disappear when the canvas is cleared.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var dd = 3;
var dd2 = 3;
var dd3 = 3;
var dd4 = 3;
var angle = 0;
var angle2 = 0;
var angle3 = 0;
var angle4 = 0;
var cx = 1000;
var cy = 1000;
var radius = 200;
var radius2 = 300;
var radius3 = 400;
var radius4 = 500;
var fps = 100;
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.strokeStyle = "skyblue";
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function draw(x, y) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
        ctx.arc((x - 50 / 2) + 25, (y - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 200, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function draw1(x1, y1) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.arc((x1 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y1 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 300, 300, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }   
    function draw2(x2, y2) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.arc((x2 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y2 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 400, 400, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function draw3(x3, y3) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.arc((x3 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y3 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 500, 500, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
        };
    }());


    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            requestAnimFrame(animate);
            ctx.beginPath();
            angle += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd / radius, 2) / 2);
            var newX = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle),
                newY = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle),
                newX1 = cx + radius2 * Math.cos(angle2),
                newY1 = cy + radius2 * Math.sin(angle2),
                newX2 = cx + radius3 * Math.cos(angle3),
                newY2 = cy + radius3 * Math.sin(angle3),
            newX3 = cx + radius4 * Math.cos(angle4),
                newY3 = cy + radius4 * Math.sin(angle4);
            draw(newX, newY);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.beginPath();
            angle2 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd2 / radius2, 2) / 2);
            draw1(newX1, newY1);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.beginPath();
            angle3 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd3 / radius3, 2) / 2);
            draw2(newX2, newY2);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.beginPath();
            angle4 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd4 / radius4, 2) / 2);
            draw3(newX3, newY3);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.closePath();
        }, 1000 / fps);
    }
    animate();
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ctx.beginPath()`, `ctx.closePath()` and `ctx.stroke()` for EVERY `arc` you create, else it will connect them with lines (as you yourself also would have to, if you were drawing and were not allowed to take the pencil off the paper):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
var dd = 3;
var dd2 = 3;
var dd3 = 3;
var dd4 = 3;
var angle = 0;
var angle2 = 0;
var angle3 = 0;
var angle4 = 0;
var cx = 1000;
var cy = 1000;
var radius = 200;
var radius2 = 300;
var radius3 = 400;
var radius4 = 500;
var fps = 100;
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.strokeStyle = "skyblue";
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function draw(x, y) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc((x - 50 / 2) + 25, (y - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 200, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function draw1(x1, y1) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc((x1 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y1 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 300, 300, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }   
    function draw2(x2, y2) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc((x2 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y2 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 400, 400, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    function draw3(x3, y3) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc((x3 - 50 / 2) + 25, (y3 - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, 500, 500, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / fps);
        };
    }());


    function animate() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            requestAnimFrame(animate);
            angle += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd / radius, 2) / 2);
            var newX = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle),
                newY = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle),
                newX1 = cx + radius2 * Math.cos(angle2),
                newY1 = cy + radius2 * Math.sin(angle2),
                newX2 = cx + radius3 * Math.cos(angle3),
                newY2 = cy + radius3 * Math.sin(angle3),
            newX3 = cx + radius4 * Math.cos(angle4),
                newY3 = cy + radius4 * Math.sin(angle4);
            draw(newX, newY);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            angle2 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd2 / radius2, 2) / 2);
            draw1(newX1, newY1);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            angle3 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd3 / radius3, 2) / 2);
            draw2(newX2, newY2);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            angle4 += Math.acos(1 - Math.pow(dd4 / radius4, 2) / 2);
            draw3(newX3, newY3);
            ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        }, 1000 / fps);
    }
    animate();
}());
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="2000"></canvas>
```

E.g. I changed the following:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
ctx.arc((x - 50 / 2) + 25, (y - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.arc(cx, cy, 200, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Into this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, 75, 75, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath(); //Added
ctx.stroke();    //Added
ctx.fillStyle = "lightgray";
ctx.beginPath(); //Added
ctx.arc((x - 50 / 2) + 25, (y - 30 / 2) + 15, 25, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath(); //Added
ctx.stroke();    //Added
ctx.beginPath(); //Added
ctx.arc(cx, cy, 200, 200, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.closePath(); //Reversed order (doesn't really matter, but looks better IMO)
ctx.stroke();    //Reversed order (doesn't really matter, but looks better IMO)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Was wandering why it always joined circles together. :D

Comment: @JordanAbbott No problem, please upvote and mark as answer if this helped you.